# How to insert excel data into database within a date range

Tags: php, excel, excel-2003

I would like to insert some excel data in range of 21 days (from day 1 until day 21)into database. Use in PHP coding :)

Can anyone give me a helping hand ,

1) If it is the first time insert excel data into the database table, the data are the whole date in excel column, after that the database will check if table is NOT empty, it will just update the data.(Will this be possible?)

2)Lets for example :   $today is 06/24 , the first day in excel file, it will only insert the whole data into database from excel file although the rest of data inside the excel column are empty. While if 06/24 is the 10th day in excel file, the database  will only update data on 06/24.

thanks~

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using php ExcelReader. It return all data in array after that you can insert it according to date rage (If exists then update otherwise insert) in your database easily. Find below link to download ExcelReader.

http://code.google.com/p/php-excel-reader/downloads/list

Comment: thanks for the fast reply.I already using the latest excelReader. But i dono how to get tha date range. I only can get 2 days from the date.

Can give me an example ? thanks a lot.

Comment: You can get date range or current date data using mysql DATE_FORMAT function as (SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE DATE_FORMAT(TABLE_DATE_FIELD_NAME, '%Y-%m-%d' )='2011-06-24')

Comment: Sorry, I want to get the date from excel column and insert into database not from the database.Sorry for confusing you from my question. I will change it into more clearly.